# Xcode 10.1, 'Element' collides with 'XML.Accessor.Element'?

Tags: swift, xml, xcode

I need to add some minor changes to iOS app.

I inherited swift 3 code. which can not build on current Xcode 10.2.1

I almost managed to build it on Xcode 10.1 except for the following errors, in `SwiftyXMLParser`, `Accessor.swift`:

```
    public func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<Accessor> {
        let generator: [Element] 

        switch self {
        case .failure(_):
            generator = [Element]() // Error 2
        case .singleElement(let element):
            generator = [element] // Error 1.1
        case .sequence(let elements):
            generator = elements // Error 1.2
        }
        var index = 0
        return AnyIterator {
            let nextAccessor: Accessor?
            if index < generator.count {
                nextAccessor = Accessor(generator[index]) // Error 1.3
                index += 1
            } else {
                nextAccessor = nil
            }
            return nextAccessor
        }
    }
```

> Error 1.1: Cannot assign value of type '[XML.Element]' to type '[XML.Accessor.Element]' (aka 'Array')
>   Error 1.2: Cannot assign value of type '[XML.Element]' to type '[XML.Accessor.Element]' (aka 'Array')
>   Error 1.3: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'XML.Accessor' with an argument list of type '(XML.Accessor.Element)'

I changed the first line to

```
let generator: [XML.Element]
```

as suggested in
https://github.com/yahoojapan/SwiftyXMLParser/issues/9
but I now get error 2:

> Error 2: Cannot assign value of type '[XML.Accessor.Element]' (aka 'Array') to type '[XML.Element]'

How can I fix it, so I can build the project?

EDIT: when trying to archive the project, I get more errors as

```
Cannot convert value of type 'XML.Accessor.Element' (aka 'XML.Accessor') to expected argument type 'XML.Element'
```

in the same `SwiftyXMLParser`, `Accessor.swift` file.

I solved these errors using `XML.Element` instead of just `Element` where needed.

Comment: A *self-contained* example demonstrating the problem would be helpful.

Comment: Btw, did you download the *latest* version of that project? The latest code differs from what you showed here, and compiles without problems in my Xcode 10.2.1.

Comment: I received zip file with swift project, which I now try to build :( If I solve errors 11, 12, 13, I get error 2, and I still cannot build the project

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I looked at the current SwiftXMlparser files and changed the line that generated error 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
case .failure(_):
                generator = [] // instead of // generator = [Element]()
```

(It was worth to learn git, I just need to remember to use it features, as "look in the current source code", as @MartinR suggested